# How do i get messages even if the app is closed

Tags: message, communication, send

It is more or less asking how Whattsapp, Instagram, Facebook etc works.
How does my Phone know i got a new message even if the app is closed

(Please dont focus that much on the examples above, it is more a general question.)

I can think of a couple of solutions:

1.My Phone asks (in the background) an api every couple of seconds and fetches the data.

2.My Phone has an on going connection over the Web(i heard of technologies like: WebSocket, WebRTC, WebTransport, (standard) sockets, TCP)

3. My Phone is running a Webserver 24/7 and gets the signal like that

So in general the question is how can my PC/Phone etc. wait for a signal/data (Im talking 1, 2 or 3 bytes) in the background efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Highly Depends on the Operating System that the Program is Running on and also each OS has its own specific Security & Privacy Policy. However, all of them have a Common Agreement that this Types of Operation should be Handled in Background Processes as Secure Lightweight as Possible. so for your listed solution the closest one is **1th** case.

**2th** Case almost Impossible because it is in Contradiction to being Lightweight
**3th** Case totally wrong way

Comment: Are there any other technologies i need to know? Even if the first one is lightest option it feels kind of wrong.